# Artemis advisory topics

Tags: spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I am looking for advisory messages for Artemis, like they exist in ActiveMQ x.5. I am using the core protocol, as I am using the core JMS Client.

What I actually want is to get notified when a queue has no consumers anymore for 10 minutes, for example.

I have only found something for the Apache ActiveMQ 5.x JMS client to enable/ disable those topics, but this does not change anything in the management console. Shouldn't I see there anything?

Can anyone explain how it is working here?

Comment: Are you using the OpenWire protocol? ActiveMQ Artemis supports [management notifications](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#management-notifications) which are similar to advisories in 5.x, but they are supported for all protocols. There is also the [NotificationActiveMQServerPlugin](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/broker-plugins.html#using-the-notificationsactivemqserverplugin) which can add additional notifications.

Comment: I am using CORE protocol, as I am using Core JMS Client.  Did I get it right, that in activemq 5.x those advisory topics are created automatically? Like for every topic, there is one advisory queue with information about consumer count and so on.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveMQ Artemis does support ActiveMQ 5.x style advisory destinations and messages. However, since you're using the core protocol those won't help you because they are only available for OpenWire clients.

You may want to use [management notifications](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#management-notifications). If so, you'd specifically want to pay attention to the notification messages whose `_AMQ_NotifType` header is `2` (i.e. consumer created) and `3` (i.e. consumer closed). Both of these messages have a header named `_AMQ_RoutingName` which indicate where the messages are routed (i.e. an address if you're using a JMS topic or a queue if you're using a JMS queue) and `_AMQ_ConsumerCount` which indicate how many consumers exist there. You can use these notification messages to keep track of the consumers and then kick off timing processes to take action when certain thresholds elapse (e.g. 10 minutes with no consumers).

You could also use a [metrics plugin](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/metrics.html) and then something like Prometheus (using the [Prometheus plugin](https://github.com/jbertram/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin)) to manage alerts like this.

Comment: Thx for you answer. When you commented yesterday, I tried those **management notifications**, because I hoped **_AMQ_ConsumerCount** could be my solution, but somehow the value for it is always 0 or 1, no matter if I create or delete a consumer. I though, that it maybe references something else. I have a multicast address in my example with two consumer-queues as subscriptions. The value is 1 then. And when I close a consumer, the value stays 1 and is not right for it.

Comment: That's odd. There are tests in the test-suite which check to ensure the `_AMQ_ConsumerCount` property contains the correct value when consumers are created or destroyed and the tests are passing. Could you work up a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which demonstrates the issue?

Comment: So far I found out, that it's only working for normal anycast addresses and queues, but not for multicast and durable-shared subscriptions. And for the parameters like "supportAdvisory", there will be created two tempQueues (one for queue and one for topic) with an ActiveMQ 5.x jms client, but nothing is sent to them somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Apache ActiveMQ Artemis enables certain [ActiveMQ Advisories](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html), by default for the [OpenWire](http://activemq.apache.org/openwire.html) protocol. The advisory addresses and queues created will be displayed on the management console, along with user deployed addresses and queues.

The `supportAdvisory` parameter could be configured on an OpenWire [acceptor](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/protocols-interoperability.html#configuring-acceptors) to enable/disable advisories, ie:

```
<acceptor name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61616?protocols=OPENWIRE;supportAdvisory=true</acceptor>
```

The acceptor's parameters can be checked by the management console at `http://localhost:8161/console/jmx/attributes?tab=artemis&nid=root-org.apache.activemq.artemis-%22<BROKER-NAME>%22-acceptors-<ACCEPTOR-NAME>`

Comment: Thx for your answer. I am already using `<acceptor name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;supportAdvisory=true;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>`, but at console/jmx I can not see this as a parameter for the acceptor. Maybe it is not recognized then? I am using CORE Protocol, as I have javax.jms.ConnectionFactory and org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.

Comment: What I actually want to do is, to get notified, when a queue has no consumers anymore for 10 minutes for example.

Comment: I think that the solution proposed by @Justin Bertram using the [management notifications](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#management-notifications) is the best option.